# JavaFX как убрать выделение в ListView

Tags: java, javafx

[image: Не убирающееся выделение]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно убирать выделение, если пользователь нажал на строку ListView, которая пуста. Из-за того что выделение не сбрасывается - нельзя понять на что именно нажали.

Comment: Ловите клик на этом поле и снимайте выделение строки, если есть.

Comment: Так а как понять что там нет строки, если getSelectedItem() возвращает не null - выделение, ведь никуда не девается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лично я делал так:

```
listView.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        System.out.println(event.getTarget().toString());
    });
```

Потом парсил строку, находил `null` и так понимал, что надо убрать выделение. Да, это плохой код, но лучшего решения не нашел)

Comment: Отлично! Это работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У `ListView` есть метод `getSelectionModel()`, у которого есть много разных методов, например, `getSelectedIndex()`, который возвращает индекс выделенной строки(конечно же, начиная с `0`). Кроме того, есть метод `clearSelection()`. Если использовать его без параметров, то снимается выделение всех строк, если указать параметр index, то снимается выделение конкретной строки.

Любая современная ide после точки показывает, какие методы есть у объекта или класса, и обычно по названию метода и принимаемых параметров понятно, для чего он нужен.

Навскидку:

```
ListView view = new ListView();
view.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    int index = view.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    view.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(index);
});
```

Comment: Ваш ответ не помогает распознать что юзер нажал не на строку, а на пустое место после того, как одна из строк была, хотя бы раз выделена. Вопрос был в другом.